# how to avoid keyboard when textfield focused in flutter

Tags: flutter, keyboard

when i touch hello TextFormField() keyboard cover my red check button
so, I have to scroll up to see whole shape of button.

[image]

[image]

is there a way to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Add resizeToAvoidBottomInset to Scaffold:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false, // add here
```

or wrap Colum with SingleChildScrollView as below:

```
SingleChildScrollView(    // wrap in
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
    
              TextFieldsHere

            ],
          ),
        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a FocusNode as:
FocusNode focusNode;
And after initializing it in initState method, you can use focusNode property of TextFormField to assign your created focusNode to that property